# How to write junit test cases for rest controller, service and dao layer using springboot?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, junit, mockito

How to write *JUnit* Test cases for *RestController*, *Service* and *DAO layer*?

I've tried `MockMvc`

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class EmployeeControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private static List<Employee> employeeList;

    @InjectMocks
    EmployeeController employeeController;

    @Mock
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Test
    public void testGetAllEmployees() throws Exception {

        Mockito.when(employeeRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(employeeList);
        assertNotNull(employeeController.getAllEmployees());
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/v1/employees"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }
```

How can I verify the *CRUD* methods inside the rest controller and other layers ?

Comment: you might ask its body as response in order to check if it was saved in database.

Comment: ok, do you know how to mock DAOlayer and service layer using JUnit and Mockito?

Comment: In an environment more real you might use `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` for testing your service when application is running and `@DataJpaTest` in order to check if some entity was saved or whatever.

Comment: Thanks, do you also know about DBUnit for DAO Layer testing?

Comment: yes, you might use that as well, but reviewing your code, looks like you are not using DAO objets.

Comment: Yes, currently I am stuck in writing the junit test cases for CRUD methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` for unit testing with your *Service Layer* mocking your *DAO Layer* components. You don't need `SpringRunner.class` for it.

[Complete source code](https://github.com/eljaiek/gateways-java/tree/master/src/test/java/com/musala/gateways)

```java
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class GatewayServiceImplTest {

        @Mock
        private GatewayRepository gatewayRepository;

        @InjectMocks
        private GatewayServiceImpl gatewayService;

        @Test
        public void create() {
            val gateway = GatewayFactory.create(10);
            when(gatewayRepository.save(gateway)).thenReturn(gateway);
            gatewayService.create(gateway);
        }
    }
```

You can use `@DataJpaTest` for integration testing with
 your *DAO Layer*

```java
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @DataJpaTest
    public class GatewayRepositoryIntegrationTest {

        @Autowired
        private TestEntityManager entityManager;

        @Autowired
        private GatewayRepository gatewayRepository;

        // write test cases here     
    }
```

Check this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing) for getting more details about testing with *Spring Boot*